# Unable to Cast JSON as Dictionary After Serialization

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

I am attempting to cast my returned JSON as a dictionary for use, but for some reason, it is not working. I do not receive any errors either which is why I am really stumped.

This block will show my serialization, and cast. My first print statement gets hit, but the second print statement is never reached.

```
do {
    let jsonAny = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    print("made it through serialization")
    guard let json = jsonAny as? [String: String] else { return } //also tried [String: Any]
    print("passed the guard let")
    let fish = self.parseFishManual(json: json)

    //print(fish.name)
    //print(fish.scientific)
} catch {
    debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
    return
}
```

Any help is appreciated with this!

edit:
The json can be viewed by going to the following link (add a number from 1 to 24 to view individual data)
https://thefishapi.herokuapp.com/api/fish/

Here is the entire URL session function:

```
func getFishSpeciesUrlSession() {

        guard let url = URL(string: URL_SPECIES) else { return }

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                debugPrint(error.debugDescription)
                return
            }

            guard let data = data else { return }

            do {
                let jsonAny = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print("made it through serialization")
                guard let json = jsonAny as? [String: Any] else { return }
                print("passed the guard let")
                let fish = self.parseFishManual(json: json)

                print(fish.name)
                print(fish.scientific)

            } catch {
                debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            //print("Data = \(data)")
            //print("Response = \(response)")
        }
```

Here is my parseFishManual method:

```
private func parseFishManual(json: [String: Any]) -> Fish {
        let name = json["name"] as? String ?? ""
        let scientific = json["scientific"] as? String ?? ""
        let environment = json["environment"] as? String ?? ""
        let biology = json["biology"] as? String ?? ""
        let description = json["description"] as? String ?? ""

        let fish = Fish(name: name, scientific: scientific, environment: environment, biology: biology, description: description)
        return fish
    }
```

Comment: jsonAny isn’t a [String:String]. Show your actual JSON.

Comment: You should cast to `[String: Any]` instead, or even `[Any]` if your JSON's root is an array.

Comment: So I also used `String: Any`, but I ended up with the same result. No error message, and no printed data. Any idea of anything else that is wrong? I will update my question with more code when I am back at my computer.

Answer (score -1):

The json that your api is returning is not in the form of `[String:Any]` but is actually an array `[[String:Any]]` i.e. an array of dictionaries

Here is what you can do.

```
do {
        let jsonAny = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        print("made it through serialization")
        guard let jsonArray = jsonAny as? [[String: Any]] else { return }
        print("passed the guard let")
        //Create your fishObject's array like this.
        let fishArray = jsonArray.compactMap({ (jsonDict) -> YourFishClass in
        //Parse your json dict array to get jsonDict
        //Return Fish object here
            return self.parseFishManual(json: jsonDict)
        })

    } catch {
        debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Your JSON is actually an Array of Dictionaries. So you should cast as `[[String: Any]]`:

```
do {
    guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [.mutableContainers]) as? [[String: Any]] else {
        return
    }

    print(json)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

By the way, your JSON in incorrect. If I try to decode the JSON from the URL I'll get:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Badly formed object around character 25701." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Badly formed object around character 25701.}

If you look in your JSON for the word `\"swarm\"` and replace it with `\\"swarm\\"` and casting it as `[[String: Any]]` it will serialize your JSON correctly. However, I don't know if you expect that word as I'm proposing.

Comment: If I change my guard let as yours shows, I get this error: `Cannot convert value of type '[[String : Any]]' to expected argument type '[String : Any]'` Also, as for my json, are you saying I need to add another \ to the words swarm? That is a word that is used in a description of one of the fish species. I added my entire session method, and also my parse method to the question.

Comment: Yes, you should add a one more slash. Because it cannot escape correctly. Also, you need to change the argument in your method. Because you are passing an Array of Dictionaries and your method is expecting a Dictionary. See like this, you need to pass a list of dictionaries and your method is expecting a single dictionary.